# How can I modify a Notification that is created with StartForeground?

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

I have a Service that needs to be run as a foreground Service. 
For that to work, a Notification has to be linked to it.

When the service is started, I set the OnGoing to true, and when the user interacts with the Notification to stop the service, I would like to change the current Notification to OnGoing(false). (So the user can dismiss the Notification, if so desired)
I want the Notification to still be visible so the user can start the Service again from within the Notification.

Normally, I would have had to use the NoficiationManager to .Notify with a specific ID and later modified it.
However, with the call to StartForeground(flags, notification), there is not option to set the ID.

How can I modify an OnGoing(true) Notification (started with the StartForeground call) to OnGoing(false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is correct: you have to use an ID and then update the notification using that ID.

The first field of the startForeground method is not a flags but an ID. Here the signature:

`void startForeground (int id, Notification notification)`

Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

So you can update the notification, using the same ID.

```
mNotificationManager.notify(sNotificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was in fact using Xamarin for Android, and in an example of theirs, the first parameter is saying that it's a flag "StartForeground ((int)NotificationFlags.ForegroundService" which is clearly wrong. I actually had to call StopForeground as well in order to get the notification dismissible.